# How to write same extension to two different version of a class

Tags: java

I am not sure how to ask this properly, but that might already be part of that question. I will start to explain what I really want to achieve and will then switch to a simpler model to post the question.

**What I want to achieve**

There are currently two active versions of the web UI framework "Vaadin": Vaadin Flow (>10) and Vaadin 8 Framework. Both have same (or similar) components. There is a [Grid](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/features) which itself has a lot of functionality. The Grids from Vaadin Flow and Vaadin 8 Framework are similar but not identical. They share similar features like they have a dataprovider which fetches the data for the grid, they have columns, ... But the related functions have different names or parameter.
I want to extend the Grid (of both versions) by a "synchronization" feature, so that several users can work with the Grid and their changes are instantly shared with the other users. I would call the result "SynchronizedGrid" which itself **is** (`extends`) the original Grid so that one can use it like the original Grid.

**My problem**

Now I would like to abstract the issue a bit and call the Grid of Vaadin 8 Framework `G8`, the Grid of Vaadin Flow `G10`.
As I want to extend `G8` and `G10` I need to have two extended classes (aka "SynchronizedGrid"), which I will now call `SG8` (which `extends G8`) and `SG10` (which `extends G10`)

How exactly can I write the synchronizing functionality once and use it for both `SG8` and `SG10`. I am thinking of a common `SG` class which I could use in `SG8` and `SG10`.

I would like to have three libraries, one for `SG` and two for `SG8` (depending on Vaadin Framework 8 and SG-library) and `SG10` (depending on vaadin flow and SG-library) with as little logic in SG8- and SG10-library and as much in SG-library as possible.

**My approaches**

- multi inheritance (`SG8 extends SG extends G8` and `SG10 extends SG extends G10`) doesn't work as java doesn't support multi inheritance.
- interfaces (`class SG8 extends G8 implements SG` and `class SG10 extends G10 implements SG`)
  could work with default implementations. That would have the benefit that I would be forced to implement in `SG8` and `SG10` the functions that are different between `G8` and `G10`. Drawback would be that I can't work on constructor level. Furthermore I don't feel comfortable to include a lot of logic in interfaces as `default`-implementations.
- containing `SG` in `SG8` and `SG10` and making them call the functions of `SG`: I feel that this would require a lot of logic in `SG8` and `SG10` (when and how to call the functions of `SG`)

I hope that there is a better approach for my problem. I would be very grateful for any hint.

**EDIT**
Currently the synchronization would look like this:

```
public class SynchronizedGrid<T extends Selectable> extends Grid<T>{
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public SynchronizedGrid(Class<T> clazz) {
         super(clazz); //adding all attributes as columns (and some more stuff)
         this.clazz = clazz;
         ... //styling, some other features
         ListDataProvider<T> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider(getStaticListOfValues());
         setDataProvider(dataProvider);
         dataProvider.addFilter(bean -> !bean.isSelected());
         addItemClickListener(clickEvent -> {
               if (clickEvent.getMouseEventDetails().isDoubleClick()) {
                    registerWork(clickEvent.getItem());
               }
         });
    }
    @Override
    public void attach() {
        super.attach();
        registerAsObserver();
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {
        super.detach();
        unregisterAsObserver();   
    }

    public List<T> getStaticListOfValues(){
         StaticListStore
             .getInstance()
             .get(clazz);
    }

    public void registerWork(T item){
         item.setSelected(true);
         ObserverStore
             .getInstance()
             .get(clazz)
             .forEach(synchronizedGrid -> synchronizedGrid.reload());
    }

    public void reload(){
        getUI().access(() -> getDataProvider.refreshAll());
    }
```

`StaticListStore` and `ObserverStore` are singletons containing a `Map<Class<? extends Selectable>,List<? extends Selectable>` respectively `Map<Class<? extends Selectable>,List<Grid<? extends Selectable>>` where the key is the class of the bean.

`Selectable` is an interface all beans for the SynchronizedGrid need to implement. It contains the methods `void setSelected(boolean b)` and `boolean isSelected()`

I tried to simplify the code as much as possible, I removed some parts (like handling "push" in Vaadin (updating one UI from another thread or UI) and included as much code in this class to have a short example. The example code is the Vaadin Framework 8 version. The Vaadin Flow version would differ in the following ways:

1. No `attach()` and `detach()` to override but use `addAttachListener()` and `addDetachListener()`
2. Not `addClickListener()` with `clickEvent.getMouseEventDetails().isDoubleClick()` but `addDoubleClickListener()`
3. All Vaadin-classes (like `Grid` and `DataProvider`) are in different packages

My question is not necessarily about that vaadin specific topic but how to do it architectural, e.g. if there are any design patterns I could use.

Comment: Ever thought of using a factory pattern? bringing all into single class might not work

Comment: @Kris: yes, a colleague of mine also suggested that but I understand factory pattern as a way to get objects (different implementations) without calling the constructor. I don't really see how that could help. What should the factory create?

Comment: In my opinion, you should have a sense of environment some-how. ie, what version of libraries are you using. Based on that , create a factory which produces objects specific to that runtime. Abstract factory pattern is good choice for this.

Comment: but that would require to have both runtimes (Vaadin Flow and Vaadin 8 Framework) in one library which clashes in a lot of ways

Comment: Not necessarily. You can opt for Reflection APIs , to load the classes and create objects, If you want to play around without conflicts.

Comment: @keanni Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the "synchronization". It is not clear where data is flowing in what direction and what the grids are sending/receiving (if they do at all). If possible provide some kind of diagram how the synchronization should work. Maybe show how the synchronization will work when you have only one version.

Comment: thanks for the hint, @Progman, I just did that

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin 14 is the only "active" one (with 15 being in Pipeline), 8 is still listed on the site because of LTS (i.e. bugfixes) for legacy applications.
For new projects or ones who work with 14 it should be 14-only. As with version 10 Vaadin changed the fundamental workflow completely, hence the "flow" starting with 10.

Edit:
If you really need to work with both one possible solution is to wrap the Grids with Adapters (which you almost do anyway with the SynchronizedGrid-idea) the Adapters themselves being subclasses/implementations of a class/interface with common functionality. Depending on your general structuring the Adapters could be each in a project with the matching Vaadin dependency. The code using the Grids won't have to know anything about them if held general and using your SynchronizedGrid-Superclass/Interface. But I see major pain, as it would require the other parts to be also in the subprojects e.g. Layout incompatibilites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not helpful. And not exactly correct. There will be even new features in vaadin 8 until 02/2022. We have legacy applications that rely on vaadin 8. My question is not related to vaadin but about the possible architecture to solve the issue